# Finding and moving all files while keeping directories intact

Tags: bash, unix, mkdir, mv

```
read source
read destination 
destination=$(cd -- "$destination" && pwd)
cd -- "$source" &&
  find . -name '*.ext1' -o -name '*.ext2' -exec sh -c '
    mkdir -p "$0/${1%/*}"
    mv "$1" "$0/$1"
  ' "$destination" {} \;
```

I have the above code which finds files and then tries to preserve the directory structure. But the issue is it doesn't find and move all files over of the type I requested - what's wrong? It seems to miss files that aren't in the lowest directory level.

```
Source/
\->File (misses this)
\->Folder/
   \->File (finds/moves this)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`-o` has lower precedence than the implied `-a` between adjacent expressions, and so

`find . -name '*.ext1' -o -name '*.ext2' -exec blah`

will be parsed as

`find . '(' -name '*.ext1' ')' -o '(' -name '*.ext2' -exec blah ')'`.

To get what you want, do:

```
find . '(' -name '*.ext1' -o -name '*.ext2' ')' -exec sh -c '
  mkdir -p "$0/${1%/*}"
  mv "$1" "$0/$1"
' "$destination" {} \;
```